# How to order given strings?

Tags: c++

I have to make algorithm which can arrange given strings as lexicographical order.
acid apple banana acquire cat crop crab power cat
->  acid acquire apple banana cat cat crab crop power
like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  char word[n][100];
  int change[n][100];
  char alphabet[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%s",&word[i]);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
      change[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
      for(int k=0;k<=26;k++){
        if(word[i][j]==alphabet[k]){
          change[i][j]=k+1;
        }
      }
      if(word[i][j]=='\0'){
        for(int k=j+1;k<100;k++){
          change[i][k]=0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
      if(change[i][j]>change[i+1][j]){
        int temp[100];
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
          temp[k]=change[i][k];
        }
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
          change[i][k]=change[i+1][k];
        }
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++){
          change[i+1][k]=temp[k];
        }
      }
    }
  }


  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
      for(int k=1;k<=27;k++){
        if(change[i][j]==k){
          word[i][j]=alphabet[k-1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%s\n",word[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My idea is each alphabet of the given strings change to numbers such as a->1
b->2, ... z->26;
Then, from first letter, it will compare the order of the number...
And again, I changed the numbers into letters. But its output is wrong...
I think that it looks not wrong... Where is wrong?enter code here

Comment: is there any reason you are not using `std::string` and `std::vector` ? because if you do then sorting is just calling the corresponding algorithm (`std::sort`, you can also use it with c-strings and c-arrays, its just a bit more painful)

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), so technically your code isn't valid C++.

Comment: Your *changing* algorithm doesn't work, `'z' + 1` is not a letter.  Look up Caesar Cipher.  You may want: `char c = (((change[i][j] - 'a') + 1) % 26) + 'a';`

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` allows easy sorting of any fitting container from the STL, like `std::list` or `std::vector`. You can feed it a function that defines a smaller-than relationship that is used to compare them.

Example:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <algorithm>
using std::sort;
using std::min;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool smaller_than(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i<min(a.length(), b.length()); i++)
    {
        if(a[i] < b[i]) return true;
        if(a[i] > b[i]) return false;
    }
    return a.length() < b.length();
}

int main()
{
vector<string> data = {"xyz", "aaa", "dg", "egseg", "xyyyyyy", "a", "z", "A", "Z" };
    sort(data.begin(), data.end(), smaller_than);

    for(const string& datum : data)
    {
        cout << datum << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This returns

```
A
Z
a
aaa
dg
egseg
xyyyyyy
xyz
z
```

Note that `smaller_than` can have different code here, allowing you to adjust the comparison to whatever you need.

If you omit the `smaller_than`, that is you write

```
    sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

it will use the < operator of the type that is currently sorted, in this case `string::operator<`. In this example, this should do the same (haven't checked exactly, though), but I wanted to include such a function to give you a tool in hand. If, for example, you would desire that the order of apple, Zebra and zebra is not "Zebra, apple, zebra" but "apple, zebra, Zebra", you could modify the comparison function accordingly.

Some hints in regard to your code:

- learn to use the STL, char arrays are pretty much C. In C++, you use some sort of string class, like `std::string`, or a class of some other library, like `QString`.
- Divide your code into modules of some sort, like functions. That you would even do in C-style procedural programming. Right now you have a bunch of for-loops that do something which you need to read closely, instead of having a name attached to it.

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that the `smaller_than` is not necessary for OPs needs. Strings compare according to their lexicographical order and `std::sort` uses that comparison by default

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you need to write a comparison function when `std::string` has overloaded `operator <`?  In other words, replace `smaller_than` with `<`.

Comment: @user463035818 It was mostly my intention to give him that option as a tool on his way. Also, note how I emphasized that 'Z' < 'a'? That is correct order, but it might be counter-intuitive to see things ordered like "Zebra, apple, zebra". This part was not necessary to answer the question per se, but it belongs to it, I feel. But I'm adding this for clarification.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to achieve this is use vectors, sort and strings. You can take input for your string in a vector as shown:

```
string s;
vector<string> v;
while (cin >> s)
    v.push_back(s);
```

And then simply sort using:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can just use built-in `std::sort` function, but all string have to contain only small/capital letters. You can store values on some STL container, for instance `std::vector`, and then call `std::sort` using `begin()` and `end()` iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    while (n--) {
        std::string s;
        std::cin >> s;
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for(auto it : v ) std::cout << it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Think about:  Will `sort` work with a string containing all upper case characters?  I believe it will.